# How to stop/hide jquery spinner after downloads completes?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, jquery-ui-spinner

In my program when user clicks the submit button (the submit button is in jsp file), the jquery spinner shows up. At the same time the request is sent to java servlet. The servlet handles the request, creates excel file and downloads the file.

But after download completes, I want to hide the jquery spinner. How am I able to do it?

Here are my codes:
Below is section of my JSP (html) code:

```
  <tr>
    <td>
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="action" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="download_token_value_id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Download" name="action" class="spinner" /> // When user clicks Download buttons the jquery spinner appears      
    </td>
</tr>


<center>

    <div id="fontSpinner" style="color: blue; display: none;" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw">
    </div>
</center>
```

Below is the script:

```
   <script>

    $('.spinner').click(function() {
        $("#fontSpinner").css("display", "block");
        }); 
</script>
```

Below is the Java servlet that creates and download the excel file

```
 response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + excelFileName + "\"");
....
....
.... // code that creates a excel file
....
....

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
workbook.write(out);

workbook.close();               
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: You cannot unless you ajax to the server and sees if the file was created successfully

Comment: @mplungjan Would you please kindly suggest me how can I implement ajax with my code. I am new in this field.

Comment: @mplungjan I will have a look on the resources. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Saroj- On Click of Download you write a javascript function and make a ajax call or http-service call to servlet. Once you get success response(200) from servlet ,put flag to disappear spinner.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

You could return a status code 200 in the header of the response and basically when the fronted receives the 200 code you set the spinners display property to none. You should also consider to set it to none when an error occurs and do a proper error handling.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I try this and let's see if it helps.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I know but what else can I do for now?

Comment: How would the spinner know the response? OP is submitting a form that does not feedback to the page it is on